# TypeError: books.map is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, rest, jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export class Books extends React.Component {
state = {
    loading: true,
    books: []
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch('**url**')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ books: data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
  }
 render() {

    const { books } = this.state;
    console.log("this.state contains:", this.state);
```

/*  this.state contains: {loading:true, books: status:'success',data:(10)[{id:1, name:xyz,..},{}..] */

```
    const b = books.data;
    return (
        <div>
            {b.map((k) => (
                <h1>{k.name}</h1>
            ))}

        </div >
    );

}
```

}

I want to display all the values(for example: id:1, name:xyz, id:2 , name:xxx)
Since 1 week I'm trying to fix this. But couldn't. getting map is not a function.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following:

```js
let b = books.data || [];
```

since you're getting data in componentDidMount, there's fair chance it doesn't get the result when you want to render.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Omg! It fixed my problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: happy tp help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `books` object in the state is initially empty, therefore `books.data` does not exist and hence `books.data.map` is not function. So do conditional render

```
    const {data} = this.state.books
    <div>
        {data && data.map((k) => (<h1>{k.name}</h1>))}

    </div >
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying this code as well. But giving me error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, my bad, well when books are empty so there is no data to destruct :) So the change says, if data exists (could be destructed from books) the render the following

Comment: According to your received data, The `books` is not an array, it is an object which contains an array. For just sake of clean code and not misleading in maintenance, change the state `books:{}`

Answer (score 0):

Try making a condition to check if b is an **array** or not! like this:

```
const b = books.data;
return (
    <div>
        {
         if(Array.isArray(b)){
        b.map((k) => (
            <h1>{k.name}</h1>
        ))
           }
            }

    </div >
);

}
```